# PHP Sax Parser and UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, saxparser

It is unfortunate that I am running into some troubles with the php sax parser and the utf-8 encoding.

The case:

I have a xml-file that is encoded in utf-8. The file is parsed using the standard php sax parser. The data is stored into some container objects and inserted into a mysql database. Unfortunately some characters look weird in the database (mostly german umlaute). For example Gürtel looks like GÃ¼rtel.

The following code fragment shows how the parser is instantiated:

```
$saxParser = xml_parser_create("UTF-8");
```

Does this suffice to parse utf-8 files? If yes, what I am missing? Some sepcial database stuff when inserting?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What colation have your database text columns? Have you set the MySQL encoding go UTF-8 using ´SET NAMES 'UTF8'´?

Comment: @ZombieHunter My collation is utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the encoding step by step to find the invalid code:

1. Print the value you retrive from the XML
2. Print out the SQL statement you build

When printing the values, make sure your browser reads the output with the correct encoding.

You have to ensure that every component uses the proper encoding:

**PHP script**

Save your PHP with the encoding set to UTF-8 **without** BOM, because this might cause problems. Use only [multibyte string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) when working with UTF-8 strings.

**XML file**

XML file starts with
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`
and the file is properly saved with the encoding set to UTF-8.

**SQL column (collation)**

```
VARCHAR(length) [CHARACTER SET charset_name] [COLLATE collation_name]
```

**Communication between MySQL server and PHP script**

Run this command right after opening the connection to the MySQL server:

```
SET NAMES 'UTF8'
```

> SET NAMES indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL
>   statements to the server.
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: Thanks to you, I was possible to figure out that the statements were not encoded corrctly. "SET NAME 'UTF8'" fixed the problem. Many Thanks!